# Creating an array in Javascript (p5.js) with several batches of random entries each with different boundary limits

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am very new to JS, and I am stuck with some basic operation: I want to create x and y coordinates using `random()` with two different sets of limits.

This is in concrete what I'm trying to do: In [this animation](https://editor.p5js.org/hosken/sketches/LRCedfGPY) there are glittering dots. I want to restrict the random location of the dots to several polygonal shapes, as though they are the facades of buildings with flickering lights of different colors.

If it was a simple rectangle, it would be easy:

```
let stars = []

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
    
    for (i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        let star = {
            x:random(width/2,width/8),
            y:random(height/2,height/4)
        };
        stars.push(star);       
    }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

    for (i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        let x = stars[i].x;
        let y = stars[i].y;
        
        fill(255);
        ellipse(x,y,random(1,3),random(1,3));
    }
}
```

But what if I want to add to `x` and `y` some additional `500` positions with the limits now being

```
            x:random(width*3/2,width/2),
            y:random(height/2,height/3)
```

I tried concatenating both as in `x:random([random(width/2,width/8),random(width*3/2,width/2)])` and several other intuitive ways, but none has yielded the intended results.

Before filling each batch of dots in each of the rectangles with different colors, the effect I'm after is something like this:

[image]

After filling in different batches with different colors, it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean add more objects to the `stars` array?

Comment: @pilchard Yes. Double the length with a batch of dots fitting into one rectangle, and a second batch on a smaller rectangle side-by-side. On the dots within the first rectangle I will choose a pattern of colors, and a different one for the dots in the second rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll just want to declare a separate function to  generate stars.

As an example a function that takes a `count` and a callback each to generate values for `x` and `y`.

```
function createStars(count, xBounds, yBounds) {
  const newStars = [];
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let star = {
      x: xBounds(),
      y: yBounds(),
    };
    newStars.push(star);
  }

  return newStars;
}
```

You can then use this in your existing `setup()` function

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  const initialStars = createStars(
    500,
    () => random(width / 2, width / 8),
    () => random(height / 2, height / 4)
  );

  stars.push(...initialStars);
}
```

as well as on it's own or within other methods to add stars at will ie. in a `mousedPressed` handler

```
function mousePressed() {
  const addMoreStars = createStars(
    500,
    () => random((width * 3) / 2, width / 2),
    () => random(height / 2, height / 3)
  );

  stars.push(...addMoreStars);
}
```

or for multiple clusters iterate over an array of objects adding each successive cluster to your global `stars` array.

```
const starClusters = [
  {
    count: 500,
    xBounds: () => random(width / 2, width / 8),
    yBounds: () => random(height / 2, height / 4),
  },
  {
    count: 500,
    xBounds: () => random((width * 3) / 2, width / 2),
    yBounds: () => random(height / 2, height / 3),
  },
];

for (const {count, xBounds, yBounds} of starClusters){
    stars.push(...createStars(count, xBounds, yBounds));
}
```

Quick snippet example adding a second cluster using the `onMousePressed` event

```js
const stars = [];

function createStars(count, xBoundsFn, yBoundsFn) {
  const newStars = [];
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let star = {
      x: xBoundsFn(),
      y: yBoundsFn(),
    };
    newStars.push(star);
  }

  return newStars;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  const initialStars = createStars(
    500,
    () => random(width / 2, width / 8),
    () => random(height / 2, height / 4)
  );

  stars.push(...initialStars);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    let x = stars[i].x;
    let y = stars[i].y;

    fill(255);
    ellipse(x, y, random(1, 3), random(1, 3));
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  const addMoreStars = createStars(
    500,
    () => random((width * 3) / 2, width / 2),
    () => random(height / 2, height / 3)
  );

  stars.push(...addMoreStars);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-WJXVjqeINVpi5XXJ2jn0BSCfp0y80IKrYh731gLRnkAS9TKc5KNt/OfLtu+fCueqdWniouJ1ubM+VI/hbo7POQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Or an example setting up with the array or objects example from above, with an added `color` callback (this could be random or in a range as you like).

```js
const stars = [];

const starClusters = [
  {
    count: 500,
    xBounds: () => random(width / 2, width / 8),
    yBounds: () => random(height / 2, height / 4),
        color: () => color(255, 204, 0)
  },
  {
    count: 500,
    xBounds: () => random((width * 3) / 2, width / 2),
    yBounds: () => random(height / 2, height / 3),
        color: () => color('#0f0')
  },
];

function createStars(count, xBoundsFn, yBoundsFn, color) {
  const newStars = [];
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let star = {
      x: xBoundsFn(),
      y: yBoundsFn(),
      color
    };
    newStars.push(star);
  }

  return newStars;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  for (const { count, xBounds, yBounds, color} of starClusters) {
    stars.push(...createStars(count, xBounds, yBounds, color));
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    let x = stars[i].x;
    let y = stars[i].y;

    fill(stars[i].color());
    ellipse(x, y, random(1, 3), random(1, 3));
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  const addMoreStars = createStars(
    500,
    () => random((width * 3) / 2, width / 2),
    () => random(height / 2, height / 3)
  );

  stars.push(...addMoreStars);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-WJXVjqeINVpi5XXJ2jn0BSCfp0y80IKrYh731gLRnkAS9TKc5KNt/OfLtu+fCueqdWniouJ1ubM+VI/hbo7POQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I understand the code in your answer, and I guess I would place in a separate `.js` file for instance. But how would I call this function to generate different arrays, or one single array with, say, the first `500` entries being for a batch in a rectangle, and the next `500` for the next one. I am really new at this!

Comment: I can't ask to dumb down the answer, but could you show how the first block in your answer would fit in the code of the OP?

Comment: Thank you very much. I was hoping for something simple, along the lines of `x = random() + random ()` or `x; random(), push(random())`. A simple concatenation. But clearly you know js, and this may not be possible.